# API creation: my action is not found (only on Linux server)

Tags: api, error

Using civix I create an extension containing a new API (WD2.importdata).
As result I obtained the file:

..ext\org.civicrmitalia.washdog\api\v3\WD2\ImportData.php

containing the following 2 functions:

```
function _civicrm_api3_w_d2_ImportData_spec(&$spec) {
}
function civicrm_api3_w_d2_ImportData($params) {
}
```

In my development server (Windows+Joomla+CiviCrm 4.7.25) the API is working properly. As I copied it in production server (Linux+Joomla+CiviCrm 4.7.25) both the API explorer and the Scheduled Jobs returns the error :

error_message": "API (WD2, importdata) does not exist (join the API
team and implement it!)

I also tried to modify the function name in "_civicrm_api3_w_d2_importdata_spec(&$spec)" or "_civicrm_api3_wd2_ImportData_spec(&$spec)", without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i have faced such problems many times in past. But i do some work around and fix it. What i would do

1. rename file ImportData.php to WD2.php
2. move WD2.php to org.civicrmitalia.washdog\api\v3\
3. Use lower case as function name. `eg civicrm_api3_w_d2_importdata($params)`

HTH

Pradeep